# Boto3 get contents of S3 bucket

Tags: python, amazon-s3, boto3

I am trying to get the list of files in a subfolder of a bucket.  Everything works fine, except, when I try to parse the files I notice that the first key my code pulls is the subfolder name.  Is there any way to leave out the subfolder name as a key?

```
s3 = session.resource('s3')
bucket = s3.Bucket('bucket_name')

for obj in bucket.objects.filter(Prefix="sub1"):
    key = obj.key
    print(key)
```

Results from print key

```
sub1/
sub1/file1
sub1/file2
.
.
```

Comment: Important side note: do not assume this value will always be present.  It is an artifact of explicitly creating the folders in the console or with certain third party tools like s3fs.  If you create the `my/example/object.txt` from the API, having never created the "my" or "example" folders directly, the folders will still appear in the console, but `my/` and `my/example/` will not be returned by the List Objects API.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd imagine there is a `.exclude` on the collections like in django but i couldn't see it as an option. You could try something like this

```
s3 = session.resource('s3')
bucket = s3.Bucket('bucket_name')
prefix = "sub1/"
data = [obj for obj in list(bucket.objects.filter(Prefix=prefix)) if obj.key != prefix]

for obj in data:
    print(obj.key)
```